# Inter Process Communication to simulate bully algorithm

Tags: windows, ipc, inter-process-communicat, bully-algorithm

I don't know alot about inter process communication 
but I want to make a simulation of the bully algorithm using inter process communication 
and after searching i found that there are mechanisms to use IPC

Clipboard
COM
Data Copy
DDE
File Mapping
Mailslots
Pipes
RPC
Windows Sockets

I don't know which mechanism is the best for this case !

I will tell you my thoughts but it may be wrong :)

I exclude these :

File Mapping is for file sharing  (which is far from our example)
COM : used for compound documents (which we don't want)
DDE : because it is usually initiated by user command and not efficient as newer technologies
File Mapping : because there is no way to guarantee that a datagram has been received. 
ClipBoard : because is almost always used for a one-time response to a user command, such as choosing the Paste command from a menu.

so the remaining mechanisms are :

Data Copy

Pipes

RPC

WindowsSockets

so which is the best mechanism to use at these cases

1) if the communication is on the same computer
2) among different computers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement of running the processes in (a) same machine, as well as (b) different machine is important, then I would choose TCP/IP Internet `socket`s (AF_INET). It works in both situations and complexity is completely hidden from the application.

(Note that, if performance is the dominating metric, then I would choose differently for case #a.)

Comment: Thank you Arun :) u mean if it will be on the same machine .. u will chose another mechanism ? which one ?